# Correct way to use prctl()

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, glibc, variadic

The prototype of `prctl` is

```
int prctl(int option, unsigned long arg2, unsigned long arg3,
          unsigned long arg4, unsigned long arg5);
```

in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) whereas in the [header](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/prctl.h;h=83049d5fe2d5204f5760afdb0bd7e40d5ea992e5;hb=HEAD) it is declared as a variadic function:

```
extern int prctl (int __option, ...) __THROW;
```

---

1. Do I have to call it with 5 arguments when I only need 2?
2. Do I need to cast args to `unsigned long`?

Answer (score 3):

Just pass what you have to pass and write 0 casted to `unsigned long` in the rest of arguments or skip them entirely. As `prctl` is declared as variadic function it will handle this situation accordingly.

```
const char* name = "The user";
if (prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long) name,
         (unsigned long)0, (unsigned long)0, (unsigned long)0) == -1)
{
    // handle error
    perror("prctl failed");
    return -1;
}
```

or

```
const char* name = "The user";
if (prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long) name) == -1)
{
    // handle error
    perror("prctl failed");
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: My concern is with the zeroes, they are promoted to `int` but the expected type is `unsigned long`. Shouldn't this be undefined behavior?

Comment: @sigsegv Yes, either cast them or skip them.